# Warn users about edit when submitting comment?

Tags: feature-request, comments, edits, answers

I am experiencing all the time:

- I wrote an answer
- I just found mistake
- I edit my answer
- Few seconds ago Original Poster comments my answer that it isn't working
- I have to reply that I edited my post and that he should recopy/repaste my code

Is it possible to create feature which would check answer against new edits before posting comments, and if answer is edited, warn user/OP about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What good would that do? Comments are extremely lightweight, if you notice that your comment became obsolete you can (and should) easily delete it. Writing a comment also does not take a long time, so the window in which this can happen is much shorter than for answers.

You can delete your own comments and flag other user's comments as obsolete if they are no longer relevant. Those are the mechanisms you should use, I see not much use for anything beyond these existing features.

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773605/can-i-parse-the-directory-listing-of-an-external-webpage/6773705#6773705) answer. (To comments). As you can see, I edited it like 3 times and OP noted that it'S not working, although it was working in time of his comment

Comment: @genesis This kind of back and forth is common, after you resolved all issues these comments are obsolete. You can then delete your own comments and flag the others as obsolete to get them deleted. I don't see how your proposal could prevent these situations, correcting a mistake *after* someone points it out is far more likely than you correcting the mistake while someone writes a comment.

Comment: Okay, I'll do so. Forgot this question (Lol. Now I'm just awaiting swarm of downvotes... :/)